# React Native + Redux component renders before store action's complete

Tags: react-native, redux

I have react native application with redux, where user get nevigated to home component after successful login. But home component get rendered before it receive user profile through store. If I use 'Home' component as connected component then on re-render it receives profile.

It is a correct flow or do I able to delay rendering of 'Home' till store is populated with new data.

Here is code

Types

```
export const FETCH_PROFILE = 'FETCH_PROFILE';
export const UPDATE_PROFILE = 'UPDATE_PROFILE';
export const DELETE_PROFILE = 'DELETE_PROFILE';
export const FETCH_STREAMS = 'FETCH_STREAMS';
```

Reducer

```
export default function profile(state = {}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

  case types.FETCH_PROFILE:

    return {
      ...state,
      profile: action.profile
    }

  case types.UPDATE_PROFILE:

    return {
      ...state,
      profile: action.profile
    }

  case types.DELETE_PROFILE:

    return {
      ...state,
      profile: null
    };

  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Actions

```
var PROFILE_KEY = "@myApp:profile";

export function fetchProfile() {
  return dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(PROFILE_KEY)
      .then((profileString) => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.FETCH_PROFILE,
          profile: profileString ? JSON.parse(profileString) :  {}
        })
      })
  } 
}

export function updateProfile(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(PROFILE_KEY, JSON.stringify(data))
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.UPDATE_PROFILE,
          profile: data
        })
      })
  }
}

export function deleteProfile() {
  return dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem(PROFILE_KEY)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.DELETE_PROFILE
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Login Component

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      error: "",
      showProgress: false,
    };
  }

  _focusNextField(nextField) {
    this.refs[nextField].focus();
  }

  _onLoginPressed() {
    this.setState({showProgress: true});
    this._login();
  }

  async _login() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch( BASE_URL + url, {
                             method: 'POST',
                             headers: {
                               'Accept': 'application/json',
                               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                             },
                             body: JSON.stringify({
                               user: {
                                 email: this.state.username,
                                 password: this.state.password,
                               }
                             })  
                           });

      let res = await response.text();
       if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          let user = JSON.parse(res);
          this.props.updateProfile(user.user);
          this.setState({showProgress: false});
          this.props.navigator.replace({name: 'Home'});
       }
       else {
         let error = JSON.parse(res);
         throw error.errors;
       }
    } catch(error) {
        this.setState({error: error});
        this.setState({showProgress: false});
        console.log("error " + error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.loginBox}>
          <TextInput
            ref="username"
            value={this.state.username}
            placeholder="Username" 
            keyboardType="email-address"
            onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username}) }
            onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusNextField('password')}/> 
          <TextInput 
            ref="password"
            placeholder="Password" 
            value={this.state.password}
            secureTextEntry={true} 
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password}) }
            returnKeyType="go"/>
          <Button textStyle={{fontSize: 14}} onPress={this._onLoginPressed.bind(this)} style={{marginTop: 30}}>
            Sign In
            </Button>
        </View>
      );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginBox: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    margin: 10,
  }
});

var {updateProfile} = require('../Actions');
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

module.exports = connect(
  null,
  (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({updateProfile}, dispatch)
  }
)(Login)
```

Home

```
class Home extends React.Component { 

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>
        <Text>Auth key : {this.props.profile ? this.props.profile.authentication_token : 'authentication_token'}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//module.exports = Home;

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

module.exports = connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      profile: state.profile
    }
  },
  null
)(Home)
```

Comment: Why don't you just display a busy spinner in `<Home/>` until the component receives the data it needs... This isnt really a react issue just the nature of asynchronous software

Comment: I am doing, but again in <Home /> I was rending another component for which I was required profile for making another api call. Which was going bit difficult. But given solution was really awesome and thank to @caojs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `redux-thunk`, you can delay the transition until data is loaded. You need to change some small things.

Add `return` to action creator.

```
export function updateProfile(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(PROFILE_KEY, JSON.stringify(data))
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.UPDATE_PROFILE,
          profile: data
        })
      })
  }
}
```

add `await`

```
if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
  let user = JSON.parse(res);
  await this.props.updateProfile(user.user);
  this.setState({showProgress: false});
  this.props.navigator.replace({name: 'Home'});
}
```